# C# - Highlight wrong controls when validating

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, error-handling

I am trying to validate windows form with try catch and so far I succeeded. My goal is when someone forgot to fill the gap or put in incorrect entry, catch returns messagebox with a warning. Now I also have Validating event on every control I want to validate so when somebody leave it empty or in incorrect format it will show the error next to the control. That seems ok so far (for me, at least) but my issue is, that if user doesn't even click to one box it only shows message box, but it won't highlight wrong controls.

Below is my code:

```
private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Book newBook = new Book(titleBox.Text, authBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(yearBox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(editBox.Text), pubComboBox.Text, descBox.Text);
            bookList.Add(newBook);
            booklistListBox.DataSource = bookList;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You probably missed a gap or put in incorrect form");
        }

    }
```

and those validating events:

```
 private void titleBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
         if (titleBox.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(titleBox, "Title is required");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
         else
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(titleBox, "");
        }
    }

    private void authBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (authBox.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(authBox, "Author is required");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(authBox, "");
        }
    }

    private void yearBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (yearBox.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(yearBox, "Year is required");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(yearBox, "");
        }
    }

    private void editBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (editBox.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(editBox, "Edition is required");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(editBox, "");
        }
    }

    private void pubComboBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pubComboBox.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(pubComboBox, "Publisher is required");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(pubComboBox, "");
        }
    }

    private void descBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (descBox.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(descBox, "Description is required");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(descBox, "");
        }
    }
```

So is there way to, I don't know, change focus or something like that, forced with pressing the create button?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [ValidateChildren()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159409%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bool gotIssues = this.ValidateChildren();
     if (gotIssues) 
     {
         // someone didn't validate well...
     }
}
```

Comment: Well how is that exactly different from my try-catch version and how can this exactly provide feedback for exact wrong control?

Comment: His method is different because it will automatically check your controls on the create button's click, as opposed to relying on a `FormatException` to tell you that something went wrong. It will actually cause your validate events to be triggered.

Comment: This one worked well, but when I got time I'll try other solutions as well :-)

Comment: But I have one think to add - since I implemented this solution, my form wont close until I fill properly gaps and save it

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue here is that you want to have it highlight in either of two scenarios:

1) When you leave the field and its contents are invalid (empty in this case)
2) When you click the create button and the field in question has invalid contents

And so I would create a single `textBox_checkIfEmpty(object sender, EventArgs e)` method:

```
private void textBox_checkIfEmpty(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var asTb = sender as TextBox;

    if (asTb != null && asTb.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider.SetError(asTb, "I'll leave it to you to abstract the error message appropriately");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider.SetError(asTb, "");
    }
}
```

Then, you can set this method as the handler for your `Validate` event on your desired required controls, and you can also call the same method from the create button's handler, looping through the required `TextBox` instances and executing the method on each.

**UPDATE**
J. Hudler's `ValidateChildren` solution would be a more (developer) efficient tail to mine, as opposed to looping through the desired controls. That said, if the form has many children, and you only need to validate several, it might be helpful to loop still. Just depends on your specific scenario. My only other question is whether or not `ValidateChildren` is infinitely recursive, or if it only goes one level down (immediate children rather than all descendants).

Comment: Well this seem to be what I am looking for, but I think that my skills in c# is not so good to understand properly - I am calling thischeckIfEmpty event on every control and this is replacing my Validating events? Sorry for being so dumm :-)

Comment: So right now, probably using the designer interface in visual studio, you have each individual control set to its particular event handler for validation. I'm saying change their validating events to point to the one handler instead--keep it more abstract.

Answer (score 0):

the event validating for control call when the mouse click on the control and then leave it from the control. In your case when the user does not click on the control it will not trigger the validating event. U can do this by making your own function and call them on creat event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1_Validating(sender);
    }

    public void textBox1_Validating(object sender)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("validating");
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "provide");
    }
```